# Sentencia SQL a Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
 select count(property_types.id) as total, property_types.types, 
 property_types.id 
 from `property_types` inner join `properties` on 
 `property_types`.`id` = `properties`.`property_type` where 
 `property_purpose` = "Sale" 
 group by `property_types`.`id
```

esta consulta me genera el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito esta misma consulta en eloquent de laravel

Intente de la siguiente manera

```
$types=DB::select(DB::raw('select count(property_types.id) as total, 
                           property_types.types, property_types.id from 
                           `property_types` inner join `properties` on 
                           `property_types`.`id` = 
                           `properties`.`property_type` where 
                           `property_purpose` = "Sale" group by 
                           `property_types`.`id`'));
```

pero me da este error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'admin_ezcabo.property_types.types' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: **select
>   count(property_types.id) as total, property_types.types,
>   property_types.id from `property_types` inner join `properties` on
>   `property_types`.`id` = `properties`.`property_type` where
>   `property_purpose` = "Sale" group by `property_types`.`id`**)

Lo que me tiene dudando es que copio y pego lo Indicado en NEGRITA del erro en  el gestor de Base de dato y me da bien el resultado

Answer (score 1):

con esto solucione.. comparto para futuros

```
$types=Types::selectRaw('COUNT(property_types.id) as total, property_types.types, property_types.id')

               ->join('properties', 'property_types.id', '=', 
                      'properties.property_type')
               ->where('property_purpose', 'Sale')
               ->groupBy('property_types.id','property_types.id','property_types.types')
               ->get();
```

Comment: Por favor considera marcar como aceptada tu respuesta y de ese modo indicar que la misma es la solución